# Do I need a Dominican Republic tourist visa as an F1 student from Saudi Arabia?

Tags: visas, f1-visas, saudi-citizens, dominican-republic

I am student with a valid F1 (student visa) status in the US. I am from Saudi Arabia. Do I need to apply for a tourist visa to go for a vacation in the Dominican Republic?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.domrep.org/visa.html, which as far as I can tell is an official DR embassy website:

> Any person who can legally travel or reside in the United States, Canada and the European Union (including Great Britain) does not need a visa to visit the Dominican Republic for tourist purposes and can enter the Dominican Republic with a Tourist Card and a valid passport.

So it would appear that thanks to your US visa status, you do not need a visa; you just need a tourist card.  You can order it [online](https://www.dgii.gov.do/Tturistaweb/) or get it at the airport when you arrive.  It costs US$10 and is valid for 30 days.

(If you didn't have a US visa, then as a Saudi citizen you would be required to get a tourist visa for the DR.)